# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv

I created a conda v-env with Python 3.8.10 and when I do `pip install -r requirements_demo.txt`, I get the following error.

```
Processing /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pycparser_1593275161868/work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: '/System/Volumes/Data/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pycparser_1593275161868/work'
```

I didn't know why it succeeded on my windows machine but on my m1 mac it just refuses to work. I have tried adding `sudo`, `-H`, `--user`, and all those yielded the same error above. I don't know what is going on now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and found this which solved it for me:

`pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt`